# How would I check to see if there are buttons on a webpage?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am creating a bot that checks to see if the Catus Trails 270 have been released and then buys them for me.

I don't know how to check and see if the button is there or not. I am going to look for the button and then if it doesn't see it, it refreshes the page and looks again.

I am using the other air maxes as an example for what the page will look like when it drops. Here is a code sample:   Thank you!

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

class catusBot:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        self.driver.get("https://www.nike.com/launch/t/air-max-2090-pure-platinum-amd?cp=usns_aff_nike_")
        if self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/section[1]/div[2]/aside/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/ul/li[11]/button") == True:
            self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/section[1]/div[2]/aside/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/ul/li[11]/button").click()
            self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/section[1]/div[2]/aside/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/button").click()
        else:
            self.driver.refresh()


my_bot = catusBot("Ethan Houseworth")
```

Comment: This site is meant to solve specific coding problems. Please be more accurate, it will help us help you : did you run the code above? At which line did it not work ?

Answer (score 0):

`find_element_by_*` methods will raise a `NoSuchElementException` if the element can not be found.  You will want to handle that.

Comment: My problem is that I have a while True in front so it just keeps refreshing even though the button is on the screen.

Comment: @ehouse I don't see the `while True` in your code block.